# Run container with volume and entrypoint from docker command/

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a container with volume and customized entry point, and then execute a `.sh` script inside the volume I shared from the docker command.

I have a folder inside my primary machine on that location: `~/vol`, and inside I have a script that I want to execute on the container.

```
[root@ilcepoc2457 vol]# pwd
/root/vol
[root@ilcepoc2457 vol]# ll
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   17 Jan 29 17:11 startup.sh
dr-xr-x---. 14 root root 4096 Jan 29 17:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   24 Jan 29 17:11 .
```

I am trying to create a container using this command:

`docker run -i -t -d --volume /vol:/vol --entrypoint "/startup.sh"  mcr.microsoft.com/playwright`

And this is the error I get:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/startup.sh": stat /startup.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just post the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: You want to be running `/vol/startup.sh`, not `/startup.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory you show is `/root/vol`, but you map `/vol`.

Your directory is mapped to the `/vol` directory, but your entrypoint `/startup.sh` says that it's in the root of the file system. Use `/vol/startup.sh` instead, like this

```
docker run -i -t -d --volume /root/vol:/vol --entrypoint "/vol/startup.sh"  mcr.microsoft.com/playwright
```

Comment: I am still getting the same issue:

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/vol/startup.sh": stat /vol/startup.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.`

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the fact that your directory listing shows the `/root/vol` directory. Try the updated command.

Comment: I am receiving `standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`, I have removed -d to see this error

Comment: That indicates that the image and your docker host aren't compatible. What type of machine is your docker host?

Comment: Actually, this in an machine i got from work, I will try with another one from out side the organization.

Comment: I was thinking if it was Windows, Mac or Linux and if Mac, what type of CPU